# Wait between dataproviders in TestNG

Tags: testng, dataprovider

I am using [DataProvider](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parameters-dataproviders) within my tests to provide data for tests. I'd like to wait between multiple tests because there is some asynchronous part that I'd like to test as well.

Is there a way how to say that there should be some Thread.sleep() between two specific data provided by DataProvider? Or can you think of any other way how to test this with DataProvider? All testsuites are designed to use dataproviders and that is also the reason I'd prefer to stick with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a data provider accepts `Iterator<Object[]>` as type, you may create your own `Iterator` implementation where you will set a `Thread.sleep()` before the first element. It will add some tempo between data providers.

Comment: Thanks, I somehow didn't realize that :)

Comment: Hey, do you have any code sample to implement this? I need to add a sleep of 2 secs between all parallel executions of DataProviders.